# php html email issue

Tags: php

THe html email is receiving as html source code not as readable text. WHy?

```
<html>
           <head>
                   <title></title>
           </head>
           <body>
                   <p style="text-align: center; ">
                           <span style="color:#ff0000;"><span style="font-size:72px;"><span style="background-color:#00ff00;">A test mail</span></span></span></p>
           </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because you have sent a plain text email into which you've written HTML. There are no shortage of tutorials on writing HTML formatted emails with PHP out there, but make sure you use one that shows you have to write a multipart MIME email rather then plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Type` to `text/html`.

Comment: @David: That's a separate issue.

Comment: It is a separate issue in the same sense that preventing SQL injection vulnerabilities are a separate issue to inserting data into a database. You don't ignore the former when explaining how to do the latter (unless you want people to make sites like [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) about you).