# Email not displaying HTML

Tags: php, html, email

I want to display the HTML I wrote in the emails that are send out to customers and admin. Right now it's just showing all the html tags.

I have this code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "myemail@myemail.com";
        $from       = $_POST['email_address'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
        $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
        $phone      = $_POST['mobile_no'];
        $customer_message = $_POST['textarea'];

        $subject  = "Spejl Blank - Klik en pris";

        $message  = "<html><body>";
        $message .= "<h1HELLO WORLD!</h1>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";
        $message .= "Du modtager her dit uforpligtende tilbud :)";
        $message .= "Din besked: " . $customer_message;

        $headers  = "From:" . $from;
        $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$message1,$headers);
        mail($from,$subject,$message,$message1,$headers2);

    }
?>
```

Comment: You also have a typo in your HTML
`$message .= "<h1HELLO WORLD!</h1>";`

Comment: ^ yeah that'll do it.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment about a typo in `$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";` - you broke the "chain link" ;-)

Comment: you also have no `$message1` and using 5 parameters in header.

Comment: In case like that just see the mail source(gmail has this feature) to view all headers and content...

Comment: about the <h1 it was just a mistake. About the $headers = "MIME" etc I don't see any problem there?

Comment: you override old `$headers` value

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig you can't keep overwriting your original post with the codes I give you. I have performed a rollback to your original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php html email issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883089/php-html-email-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36426850/1

Here's the deal. Your code has a missing `>` for `<h1HELLO WORLD!</h1>` so that'll need to be changed to `<h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>`.

Edit: Ah, now you edited that in now https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36426850/2, yet the following still applies.

Then the "chain link" broke in `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";` where there's a missing dot/concatenate.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
```

Then you're using 5 parameters in the headers which won't work. There is a 5th for `mail()` but that's for something entirely different.

Read the manual on it:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You also on top of that, don't have anything assigned to `$message1` yet that would be useless to use anyway.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit:**

Another thing is that you need to create new headers to get the other mail sent as HTML, and that is most likely why you said it wasn't sending as HTML.

Only the first mail sent will be HTML and not the second one. Consult one of my answers on Stack to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382062/ and add new HTML headers for each of them, using different variables for each header just as you did for `$headers2` and apply that to your code using the same way you used the HTML for `$headers`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just tried your changes but it still doesn't work. I have removed $message1 and i've added the dot before the "="

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig You're welcome. Read the manual on `mail()` as per the link I gave you in my answer and follow it to a "T".

Comment: I will do, thanks a lot!

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig something else I noticed is that you need to move `$message .= "</body></html>";` after `$message .= "Din besked: " . $customer_message;`.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig another thing is that you need to create new headers to get the other mail sent as HTML, and that is most likely why you said it wasn't sending as HTML. Only the first mail sent will be HTML and not the second one. Consult one of my answers on Stack to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382062/